# Commercial term "freezer bag"

Tags: traducción, comida, solicitud-de-término, argentina

I'm in Argentina, so it would be much helpful to get an answer directed to the region.

I want to refer to "freezer bags" in Spanish. I know Spanish, so I imagine you can say "bolsas de congelador" or "bolsas de congelados", but I want to know if there is an official term for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No creo que haya algo así como "oficial". En Argentina es común referirse a ellas como "bolsas para freezer". No sonaría natural alguien diciendo "bolsas para congelador".

Comment: Yes, *bolsas para freezer* is the term used in Argentina.

Comment: Yes, in Buenos Aires at least I never heard "congelador" instead of "freezer". "Freezer" is more common.